# Rails update_nested_attributes. HOw do update if exists, create if it does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Say I have two tables, `trees` and `apples` and a joined table `tree_apples`. Say the `tree_apples` table has a couple of important columns called `rotten` (boolean) and `branch` (int).

Say in the controller for `trees`, I have this:

`@tree.update_nested_attributes(tree_params)` and my `tree_params` method look like this:

```
tree_apple_params: {
    :apple_id,
    :rotten,
    :branch
}
```

Say the tree that I'm updating already has a tree_apple with an id of 3 that is `rotten: true` and `branches: nil` and the incoming params into this controller to update the branch has params that look like this:

```
tree_apple_params: [{
   apple_id: 3,
   rotten: nil,
   branch: 5
  },
  { 
   apple_id: 4,
   rotten: nil,
   branch: 6
  },
  ...
]
```

So it's params to create or update a bunch of `tree_apples`. The page that the params came from wants to update the branch for `tree_apple` that references the `apple_id` of 3, and for this `tree_apple` it doesn't provide any input about the rotten state. I do NOT want to create another `tree_apple` that references `apple_id: 3` that has `nil` for the rotten_state. I want to update the existing `tree_apple`. So, for this `tree_apple`, I'd like to find it, and then **update** it with branch 5. But for all the other params that reference apples that do not exist on this tree, I'd like to **create** new `tree_apples` if the `tree_apple` doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this? Does this logic belong in the controller or in the model as a callback of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [find_or_create_by](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Something along the lines of:

```
tree_params.each do |params|
    tree_apple = TreeApple.find_or_create_by(apple_id: params[:apple_id])
    tree_apple.update_attributes(branch: params[:branch], rotten: params[:rotten])
end
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id of the `tree_apple` record if you want to update it e.g.

```
tree_apple_params: [{
 id: 1, #passing the id of the tree_apple record here will update existing records
 apple_id: 3,
 rotten: nil,
 branch: 5
},
{ #passing NO id here will create records
 apple_id: 4,
 rotten: nil,
 branch: 6
},
...
]
```

And obviously allow the id in your params:

```
tree_apple_params: {
    :id,
    :apple_id,
    :rotten,
    :branch
}
```

Comment: Can you update `tree_apples` by any any other attribute besides id? Can you tell rails to update as long as teh `apple_id` is the same instead?

Comment: If you don't pass the id, you have to find the record to update it as @George has suggested in his answer